# Java - How to check if dynamically instantiated method is called at runtime?

Tags: java, testing, reflection, junit, invoke

Using reflection in Java, I've written some code to iterate through an arraylist of the names of classes I want enabled, instantiate them and in turn invoke a method with the common name 'parse(String)' within each.

```
for (String parser : enabledParses)
{
    Class<?> parserClass = Class.forname(String.format"%s.%s", parserDirectoryPath, parser));
    Method parseMethod = parserClass.getMethod("parse", String.class);
    Object parserObj = null;

    switch (parser)
    {
        case "parser1" : 
            parserObj = parserClass.getConstructor(ConfigWrapper.class, Alerter.class).newInstance(config, alerter);
            break;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
    parseMethod.invoke(pluginObj, stringToParse);
```

When testing, how can I check to see that the parse() method has been called for each of the enabled parsers?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way to check if they were called is if you add code to those methods to record they were called, or you check the results of the calls.

Comment: To add insult to injury, parse() is a void method. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to verify, that some method was called, you can use Mockito and then Mockito.verify (....).
But in this case your test is to big, because your implementation is too big, try to make better decomposition. Split it to more method, which are simple.
For example:

```
List<MyInterface> loadAndCreateInstances(File ...)
```

and

```
void callParse(List<MyInterface> instances) {}
```

Then use Mockito and create List of mocked/spyed objects (Collections.singletonList(myMock)). Verification:

```
Mockito.verify(myMock,times(1)).parse(any())
```

Let me know, if I said all :-)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!